# Mysql replication dump without down time? empty sql file

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump

I try to create dump as replication master data and use followed command
 to create dump, but sql file only contains paramters and there is no data and structure.
The command is :

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 -A > bckp.sql.gz 

Contents of sql file is:
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    Database: XXX
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2013-12-26  8:56:27
```

Why does this problem occur?

Comment: Please run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` and tell us the output.

Comment: File:mysqlbin.001698                                   Position:83144283                                         Binlog_Ignore_DB:mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is `--flush-log` option. I don't know why this causes the problem, but `mysqldump` works correctly after I remove the option.